# React Native - Press going through an absolute positioned View and focusing input

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, layout

I'm trying to create a positioned absolute View with some options listed inside of it but I'm having a problem with touch gesture while TextInput is behind it.

***Issue:*** When position absolute View is opened and I try to click on it (let's say that I want to click on the option inside of it ), TextInput is getting focused... It's like that View is not being registered by touch at all.

**NOTE:** This is only happening on Android device

Please check this Snack that I created as a reference -> https://snack.expo.io/@sempa/5788f2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.touchableWrapper}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.touchable}
          onPress={() => setIsOpened(!isOpened)}>
          <Text>Click To Open</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {isOpened && <View style={styles.absoluteWrapper}></View>}
      </View>
      
      {!isOpened && (
        <View>
          <TextInput placeholder="Start typing..." style={styles.inputText} />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
```

You can easily modify like this

Comment: thanks for the reply but yeah I see that this is kind of a workaround but Is there any way to fix this without having to hide TextInput component?